# C# lambda Expression In where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, lambda

I’m having issues creating an Where clause using C# and lambdas.

I have the following method GetRecommendedstudents(Guid studId)

The variable string filtersByRoles can hold a comma-delimited value such as: "xp,windows,windows8  or "xp,windows,windows8,windo " etc..

I then have the following C# lambda query:

I need get data from database by comparing 2 fields.

```
enter code here  
 var student= DataContext.students.Find(studId);
 ex: var x = DataContext.students.Where(L => (L.job == student.studentJobLocation)).AsQueryable();
```

Next i want comapare student know os("xp,windows,windows8 )

```
 ex: var y = x.students.Where(L => (s => (s.jobOperaitngsys.Split(',') == student.studentknowOS)), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

How to compare this to fields? jobOperaitngsys and  studentknowOS

Comment: Please describe the problems you found when you tried to use the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use contain. because split returns string array.

```
 s.jobOperaitngsys.Split(',').Contains(student.studentknowOS)
```

Comment: StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries ,here it's showing error that  cant used as statement.

Comment: y = x.students.Where(s => s.jobOperaitngsys.Split(',').Contains(student.studentknowOS));

Comment: hi,it geting exception    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] Split(Char[], System.StringSplitOptions)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.